# Can UnitsNet parse a string for the units as well as the value?

Tags: c#

I am looking for a library to use in my WinForms application that will allow the user to perform a unit conversion query, in text form, similar to how Google lets you do it. Example:

`5 lbs in kg`

I installed [UnitsNet](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet#culture) and searched the ObjectBrowser for "parse" but only found a `UnitsNet.AmbiguousUnitParseException` class, which probably doesn't bode well for my goal ;)

I am willing to do some of the parsing myself, like separating "5", "lbs" and "kg" in the above example but it is not obvious to me from the initials docs that UnitsNet can parse "lbs" and "kg" for example.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? UnitsNet looks like a nice, simple library for use in .NET but is there a better converter library that does what I need?

Comment: The Readme for that project seems to have some examples for parsing as well as dynamic conversion. Perhaps the 'creating a dynamic unit converter app' section (and the previous section about parsing) might be of some help

Comment: I loaded UnitConverter WPF sample w/unresolved refs: `MahApps.Metro`, `Sys.Win.Interactivity` and `UnitsNet` itself. Why can't I just fire up the .sln. It asked for .NET 462 but when I d/l it, says I already have a newer version (4.7, from VS2017). Frustrating. 

From the code, I guess it's down to reflection, adding "quantity" to `$"UnitsNet.Units.{quantity}Unit"`, like "Mass" or "Length", for eg. Again for the method, like "From{x}", like "Kilograms" or "Meters". Seems I need to do a bunch of mapping "kg, kgs, kilo, kilos, kilogram(s)", teasing out the correct name. ie parsing's up to me?

Comment: No idea. Never used the project before

Comment: Regarding UnitConverter WPF sample, you need to [restore nugets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore) first. I thought it did so on first build, but maybe you have to manually restore them.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2020-10-19**

With UnitsNet 4 you can do this:

```
var kgs = UnitConverter.ConvertByAbbreviation(5, "Mass", "lbs", "kg"); // 2.26796185
```

See [Dynamically Parse Quantities and Convert to Units - README](https://github.com/angularsen/UnitsNet#dynamically-parse-quantities-and-convert-to-units)

**Old answer**

There is no built-in free form text parser, but it does support parsing strings like `"1 kg"` and `"1m"`.

A very naive text parser, to parse the input `"5 lbs in kg"` can be done with something like this:

```
string input = "5 lb in kg";
string[] parts = input.Split(new[] { " in "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string massText = parts[0];
string toUnitText = parts[1];

MassUnit toUnit = UnitSystem.Default.Parse<MassUnit>(toUnitText);
Mass mass = Mass.Parse(massText);
double toValue = mass.As(toUnit);

Console.WriteLine(toValue); // 2.26796185
```

UnitsNet currently lacks the ability to work generically with quantities and units, so in this example we expect only `MassUnit`. The library *could* enumerate all unit enums for you and return the one that succeeds, but that is not in place as of now. You can easily do that yourself though by enumerating some unit enums of interest, or all of them, and trying to parse until one of them succeeds.

Naturally it would need a lot more work to support truly free form text, but if you have some known text patterns where you can extract `source value`, `source unit` and `target unit` with regex or more sophisticated tools then you can absolutely accomplish this.

P.S: `lbs` was surprisingly not a supported abbreviation for pounds, so I just added it now in UnitsNet v3.102.0.

Comment: Looks like the library has been updated since you posted this, there is now an error for 'UnitSystem.Default', this should be the correct line (at least it works for me): 

Enum toUnit = UnitParser.Default.Parse(toUnitText,typeof(MassUnit));

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer to show how to enumerate all the unit enums, so that it keeps trying to identify the units? The 'MassUnit' enum is in a namespace, which makes it difficult to deal with (I think reflection may need to be used to grab all the unit enums?). I think this would be useful to any future readers.

Comment: I updated the answer with an easier approach in more recent versions of the library. Let me know if that helps. @Diomoid